# Format output to list

Tags: ansible

I'm working on an ansible playbook. I'm checking for new package patch versions of software, these versions are part of a list.

My code looks like this atm, credits for building the list goes to @Zeitounator

```yaml
- name: get list of all supported version packages
    shell: |
      set -o pipefail
      repoquery --cache --showduplicates --qf "%{VERSION}" --enablerepo xyz abc \
      | grep -E -- "13." \
      | sort --unique --version-sort
    changed_when: false
    register: versions

  - name: get the major versions
    set_fact:
      major_versions: >-
          {{
            versions.stdout_lines
            | map('regex_replace', '^(\d*\.\d*)\.\d*$', '\g<1>')
            | unique
            | sort
          }}


  - name: Create a consolidated list per major version
    set_fact:
      consolidated_versions: >-
          {{
            consolidated_versions | default([])
            +
            [{'major_version': item, 'patch_versions': versions.stdout_lines | select('contains', item) | list }]
          }}
    loop: "{{ major_versions }}"
```

My first task was to check the patch levels only through their corresponding major versions.
For example:

Check version 13.0.[1-10] only in folder 13.0, 13.1.[1-5] only in folder 13.1 etc.
This works as expected.

What I want to do now is to download only the latest package version of a major version, so I only need a list with the patch version numbers, like this:

- 13.0.10
- 13.1.5
- 13.2.2

I tried it with another `set_fact`

Like this:

```yaml
- name: get latest patchversion of supported version
    set_fact:
      patch_version: "{{ consolidated_versions | json_query('[*].patch_versions[-1]') }}"


  - name: output the last versions
    debug:
      var: patch_version
```

This gives me an output like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "patch_version": [
        "13.0.10",
        "13.1.5",
        "13.2.2"
    ]
}
```

This is indeed the data I need.
I need to use these 3 elements in a loop to download the packages like this:

```yaml
- name: Download the files
    get_url:
      url: https://packages.xyz.com/abc/def/packages/el/{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/abc-def-{{ item }}-ee.0.el{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.x86_64.rpm/download.rpm
      dest: /var/www/html/abc/{{ date }}/abc-def-{{ item }}-ee.0.el{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.x86_64.rpm
    loop: "{{ patch_version }}"
```

Problem is now that ansible does not handle the fact as a list, so it replaces `{{ patch_version }}`with this: `['13.0.10', '13.1.5', '13.2.2']`
Of course, this won't work.

How do I transform this output into a loopable list?
I already tried to make it a list, but then I got the whole output as a string as one element. How do I split this into a list like this:

```
- 13.0.10
- 13.1.5
- 13.2.2
```

?

Thanks in advance, I'm so confused.

Comment: `['13.0.10', '13.1.5', '13.2.2']` is a representation of a list in json (and by extension in yaml as well). From your debug, it is definitely a list. What is the error your get when looping over it ? Note that in your task, in `dest` and `url` params, you should replace `{{ patch_version }}` (i.e. the full list you are currently looping over) by `{{ item }}` (i.e. the current element in the loop).

Comment: The error I get is a "URL can't contain control charaters", as I said, the get_url module doesn't take the variable as a list, in the URL `{{ item }}`is replaced with the whole string you posted in your comment. See: `abc-def-['13.0.10', '13.1.5', '13.2.2']-ee.0.el8.x86_64.rpm/download.rpm`

Comment: List is working here for example https://pastebin.com/2hB8jiuV - I don't get it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by myself, not sure what the bug was, maybe just my mess ;).
For testing purposes I tried some things with `with_nested` and with `loop`.
So my code looked like this for a while:

```yaml
- name: Download the files
    get_url:
      url: https://packages.xyz.com/abc/def/packages/el/{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/abc-def-{{ item }}-ee.0.el{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.x86_64.rpm/download.rpm
      dest: /var/www/html/abc/{{ date }}/abc-def-{{ item }}-ee.0.el{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.x86_64.rpm
    loop:
      - "{{ patch_version }}"
      # - commented out loop
      # - another commented out loop
```

At this case the list seems to be read as a string.
So ansible replaces the variable with the all values as a string into my code.

After I changed the code to:

```yaml
- name: Download the files
    get_url:
      url: https://packages.xyz.com/abc/def/packages/el/{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/abc-def-{{ item }}-ee.0.el{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.x86_64.rpm/download.rpm
      dest: /var/www/html/abc/{{ date }}/abc-def-{{ item }}-ee.0.el{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.x86_64.rpm
    loop: "{{ patch_version }}"
```

It worked as expected. Thanks for the hints, maybe my brain's a little bit confused after the whole day working on that playbook ;)

Comment: In your fist form, you are passing to the loop a list which contains a single element which is itself a list, ie. you are looping only once over a single item which is a list. If you ask to output that item, you get a string representation of a json list.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem because fact is handled as list in my ansible version (ansible 2.9.6, python 3.7.3).

Nevertheless, if fact is a string try to pass it through from_json filter:

```
 loop: "{{ patch_version | from_json }}"
```

FWIW, you can check variable type piping it into type_debug:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ patch_version | type_debug }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Things getting more weird, with the `type_debug', it says "list" :) I'm on ansible 2.9.11 and python 3.8.5. I'll try to debug it more and play around with the list with other modules.

Comment: Look at this pastebin: [https://pastebin.com/2hB8jiuV - the list is indeed working here but it's not in the get_url module. I'm on Ansible 2.9.11 an Python 3.8.5

Comment: @diggnsaegg could it be that control character get_url complains about comes from another variable? Try to echo url to see what is actually generated.

Comment: I fixed it, look at my answer below :) Thanks for the input!